# What is supposed to be in __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am trying to create a Python package. You can have a look at my awful attempt [here](https://github.com/jmcurran/imgur-album-downloader/tree/jmc001).

I have a module called `imguralbum.py`. It lives in a directory called `ImgurAlbumDownloader` which I understand is the name of the package -- in terms of what you type in an `import` statement, e.g.

```
import ImgurAlbumDownloader
```

My module contains two classes `ImgurAlbumDownloader` and `ImgurAlbumException`. I need to be able to use both of these classes in another module (script). However, I cannot for the life of me work out what I am supposed to put in my `__init__.py` file to make this so. I realize that this duplicates a lot of previously answered questions, but the advice seems very conflicting.

Comment: Anything you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have to figure out why (I have some ideas), but this is now working:

```
from ImgurAlbumDownloader.imguralbum import ImgurAlbumDownloader, ImgurAlbumException
```

The trick was adding the package name to the module name.

Answer (score 0):

It sure sounds to me like you don't actually want a package. It's OK to just use a single module, if your code just does one main thing and all its parts are closely related. Packages are useful when you have distinct parts of your code that might not all be needed at the same time, or when you have so much code that a single module would be very large and hard to find things in.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght. The reason for the package is because I am calling this code in another module I am working on. Simple solution, as you point out is to just stick my module in the same directory. However, because neither original module is my own, I wanted to write it in such a way that people could get the latest version of the downloader, independently of the other script.